# For a case of arbitrary sets $D_i$, $f$ might not be continuous even if all $f|_{d_i}$ are continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be the union of the closed sets $D_1, . . . , D_r ⊆ ℂ$. Show the following: A function $f : D → ℂ$ is continuous if and only if all restrictions $f|_{d_i}, i = 1, . . . , r$, are continuous. Further show that in case of arbitrary sets $D_i$, $f$ might not be continuous even if all $f|_{d_i}$ are continuous.

Doing my own study to prepare myself for uni has been quite tough, especially with taking a gap semester. How does one appropriately answer this question?

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a function is continuous if the preimage of any open set is open. Here, each $D_i$ is assumed to be toplogized as a subspace of $D$.

Let $U\subseteq \Bbb C$ be open. If $f\colon D\to\Bbb C$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $D$, hence $f^{-1}(U)\cap D_i$ is open in $D_i$ for every $i$. Thus $f|_{D_i}$ is continuous. Conversely, suppose $f|_{D_i}$ is continuous for every $i$ and take $U$ open in $\Bbb C$. The sets $f^{-1}(U)\cap D_i$ are all open, hence $$\left(f^{-1}(U)\cap D_1\right)\cup\cdots\cup \left(f^{-1}(U)\cap D_r\right)=f^{-1}\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^rD_i\right)=f^{-1}(U)\cap D=f^{-1}(U)$$
is open. This shows $f$ is continuous.

This statement definitely fails if we allow arbitrarily many $D_i$. Take $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to be any discontinuous function and $D_i=\{i\}$ for every real number $i$. The restriction $f\colon \{i\}\to \Bbb R$ is continuous even though $f$ is not.

Comment: Do you mind explaining further? Still a little confused

Comment: Sure; which part?

Comment: Why is $f^{−1}(U)∩D_i$ open?

Comment: If $f|_{D_i}$ is continuous, $(f|_{D_i})^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)\cap D_i$ is open in $D_i$ since $U$ is open in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: $f|_{D_i}$ is the restriction of function $f$ to domain $D_i$ right?

Comment: Yes$\hspace{0pt}$